# What's for dessert?

Tags: mathematics, cipher

Another puzzle, yay! What do I want for dessert?

> 1. An element, a blue liquid you breathe.
> 2. The end of a sentence.
> 3. wgpz tzggjr wgvxf bmzzi mzy
> 4. It's three til' 4, plus forty more.

Hint:

> Each clue relates to a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> pi e = 8.5397... Well, who doesn't want pie for breakfast? In all honesty I figured out the pun first then made the clues match.

An element, a blue liquid you breathe.

> Oxygen is atomic number *8*

The end of a sentence.

> Full stop/period, i.e. a *decimal point*. Note the hint said the answers /relate to/ a number, not are numbers

wgpz tzggjr wgvxf bmzzi mzy

> Caesar cypher key is *5*. (giving "blue yellow black green red", as mentioned in previous answers)

It's three til' 4, plus forty more.

> 3 til 4 is 3:57, +40 = *3:97*... Thanks to @hexomino in the comments for improving on my original answer.

Comment: +1 Great answer, I would say the last clue is 3:57 = 357 + 40 = 397. What you say in the last line isn't entirely correct. Specifically, there are definitely more than 40 more but, interestingly, the general characteristic is not known.

Comment: Ah thanks @hexomino, that makes WAY more sense, I'll update with your improvement :)

Comment: Also, as @rhsquared said, the colors are the Olympic rings. There are 5 rings, 5 colors, and the shift is 5!

Answer (score 0):

*Partial* Solution:

Line One:

> Nitrogen - number 7 on the periodic table

Line Two:

> A Period...maybe you want an ascii code?

Line Three:

> blue yellow black green red - maybe hex codes?

Line Four:

> 537

Comment: Aw, you got it wrong. It's kinda correct, though. ruggcf://lbhgh.or/cC44RCOZo8N?g=441

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

1st line

> Oxygen - atomic number **8**, it's in air and also is blue when in liquid form

2nd line

> As @Brandon_J said, period. Maybe that's the answer, just a '**.**' since it appears in decimal numbers

3rd line

> translates to "blue yellow black green red" in ROT5, so **5** is the answer?

4th line

> no idea so far

Answer (score 0):

other partial answer, based on Quantoss and Brandon_J assumptions
1

> oxygen = 8

2

> '.'  ascii code = 46  or  hex code is 2E

3

> 5

4

> 3 'til 4  is 1 or 7  "plus 40 more"  either 41 or 47

then I think we should

> use the [leet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet_speak) alphabet to decypher, possibilities are:
> 846541 = babsai / babsal
> 82E541 = bresai / bresal
> 846547 = babsat
> 82E547 = bresat
>  6 can also be 'g'
> none of them are dessert :(

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

An element, a blue liquid you breathe.

> Both oxygen and nitrogen when liquid are pale blue liquids. It could be N or O with atomic numbers 7 and 8. Another point - they will be in molecule form so it's more correct to be N2 and O2 which makes the numbers 72 or 82.

The end of a sentence.

> Full stop, . or period, ASCII CODE 46 (0x2E)

wgpz tzggjr wgvxf bmzzi mzy

> Rot5 gives us the colours of the [olympic rings](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Olympic_rings_without_rims.svg/1200px-Olympic_rings_without_rims.svg.png&imgrefurl=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_symbols&h=554&w=1200&tbnid=-LBvV73wZXtObM:&q=olympic%20rings&tbnh=98&tbnw=214&usg=AI4_-kTMInx3E7UIaVJX_4EB5xcJFuYWiQ&vet=12ahUKEwijjoiwjPLfAhXSTBUIHVIZCcsQ9QEwAHoECAcQBg..i&docid=QVEM3dbrXvvEnM&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijjoiwjPLfAhXSTBUIHVIZCcsQ9QEwAHoECAcQBg). Maybe it's the next olympic games in Tokyo in 2020, or it could be 1896, the year in which the moderl Olympics were restarted.

It's three til' 4, plus forty more.

> 3 till 4, that's  3:57 or 15:57 plus 40 more gives 4:33 or 16:33. Or it could be as @Flying_whale pointed, 3 to 4 that is an interval of 1, so the result is 41